# FTP to a server through a VPN on the same server?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, ftp, openvpn

I have a remote server (at home but I'm at university) which is running a VPN, I am connecting through the university network, through the vpn server to the internet.

That server does a bit of everything including file storage and I want to connect to it through FTP.

If I am connecting to the VPN example.com and I open an FTP connection to example.com will it go through the VPN, into the internet and back into itself or will it just go directly?

I am running OpenVPN on Ubuntu. I hope this makes sense, let me know if I need to explain something differently.

Comment: Also, I think Super User is the right site for this but let me know if I'm wrong and I'll post on another Stack Exchange site :)

Comment: Is the a question of speed slowing that may be caused?

Comment: @ohope5 Somewhat, I was more interested in how it would work but speed slowing would be a concern for me I guess